# Visual Studio Online - Running AUtomated Tests linked to User Stories

Tags: visual-studio, testing, automated-tests, azure-devops

I'm trying to understand how to use visual studio online. I have a user story and it has linked to a test case.

This test case has an automated test case (which is a unit test in my test project).

[image]

The test case is:
[image]

I have it running my tests on build, but even after a successful test run the little beaker thing tool-tip on the user story shows 0 passed, 0 failed and 1 pending. I have to manually pass the test. I assume this is because I have no steps in the test. I don't want it to be a manual test though.

Is their anyway to have it run and pass my tests and have this reflected on the user story? (If I pass it manually, a little green tick appears next to the beaker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you specified corresponding test plan and test suite for Run Functional Tests step/task.

[image]

You can click open test suite icon to navigate to corresponding test suite.

[image]